# Wordpress Comments box is not coming on custom post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add comments box **comments_template();** on the custom post but not sure why it is not coming? Please have a look on the following code and let me know what is the mistake I am doing?

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=1' . '&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>


<?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

<nav id="nav-posts">
  <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('PREVIOUS POSTS'); ?></div>
  <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('NEXT POSTS'); ?></div>
</nav>

<?php } else { ?>

<nav id="nav-posts">
  <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('PREVIOUS POSTS'); ?></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you add 'comments' in supports when register  custom post type?

Comment: Do you have "comments.php " file in your theme root folder.

Comment: @ Atif Tariq: Thank you for your quick response. I don't have comments.php file in themes root folder. Comments box was coming fine without registering custom post type via different code style. I had to changed the code style because of page navigation.

Comment: Your problem solved?

Comment: No, issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Register Custom Post Type Like this:

```
$args = array(
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-format-video',
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            //'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'menu_position'      => null,
            'supports'           => array('title', 'editor', 'comments')
        );
        register_post_type( 'custom_type', $args );
```